# Proof of $(a+b)^x=a^x+b^x$ implies $x=1$

Tags: functions

> I'd like to prove that for $a,b>0$, 
>   $$(a+b)^x=a^x+b^x \implies x=1.$$

I tried to study the variation of the map $f:x\mapsto (a+b)^x-a^x-b^x$ but unfortunatly it's not monotone since 
$$f'(x)= (\ln (a+b)-\ln (a))a^x + (\ln (a+b)-\ln (b))b^x .$$
Taking $\ln$ in the equation doesn't seems to help either.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: $a, b, c \in ?$

Comment: Use binomial/taylor expansion on (a+b)^x

Comment: There is no $c$, $a,b$ are real numbers such $a,b>0$.

Comment: Do you want to show that there is no $x\neq 1$ such that this holds for all $a,b>0$? Or do you want to show that there is no $x\neq 1$ such that this holds for some $a,b>0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(a+b)^x=a^x+b^x$ equivalent $1=(\frac a {a+b} )^x+(\frac b {a+b} )^x $

Because $0 \lt \frac a {a+b} \lt 1, 0 \lt \frac b {a+b} \lt 1$, the right side is strictly decreasing, therefore the solution $x=1$ is unique

Answer (score 0):

You can do this even more simply: let $a=b=1$. Then on the left, $2^x$, and on the right, $1+1$.

EDIT: Though I may have misunderstood your question. I answered it as if you asked "If this holds for all $a,b$, then show that $x=1$". You may be asking instead "If this holds for some $a,b$, then show that $x=1$".